# Upgraded to 17.04. How do I destroy my swap partition and live 17.04 to the fullest?

Tags: partitioning, swap, 17.04

How do I correctly implement the swapfile the way 17.04 would if I didn't have a swap partition?

I want it to be dynamic, and the only instructions I can find are for creating hard-sized swapfiles.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This is not dynamic. The tutorial shows how to make a 1G hard-sized swapfile. I have already created such a ghetto swapfile. the tutorials are numerous, common, and easy to find. There were even at least 2 good ones on askubuntu.

Comment: From the comments in https://askubuntu.com/a/904632/462004 it seems that it's only dynamically at install-time, i.e. `patman-swapfile` makes the decision based on how much space there is at the time of the installation.