# Not able to create home partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 18.04

I have a laptop with a 1TB HDD which is divided into two drives, C & D. The C drive is used for Windows 10. I am installing Ubuntu on the D drive, but at the time of creating swap and root partitions I am not getting an option to create a home partition.

How can I create a `/home` partition during installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and [Have Swap Files Been Used on Ubuntu Prior to 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048128/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a /home/ pick the option "something else" and create a mount point for / and  /home/ yourself. Don't bother with a swap partition though: we use a swapfile in Ubuntu.