# Fstrim is causing high boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, performance, logo

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, dual-booted with Win10. Whenever I boot the system, it takes ~3 minutes. Also before the login screen, this thing comes up of which I am attaching a screenshot.
 [image: unknown logo]

What does this logo stands for and if this is the reason for high boot time, how to get rid of it?

This is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
    3min 28.455s apport-autoreport.service
    3min 20.522s fstrim.service
         51.936s dev-sda5.device
         48.922s systemd-journal-flush.service
         40.451s apparmor.service
         38.857s binfmt-support.service
         38.828s snap-vlc-770.mount
         38.827s console-setup.service
         38.806s dns-clean.service
         38.802s qemu-kvm.service
         36.102s snap-core18-1066.mount
         31.498s snap-sublime\x2dtext-58.mount
         29.766s snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-5.mount
         29.665s snap-gimp-165.mount
         29.496s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
         29.382s snap-sublime\x2dtext-67.mount
         29.351s snap-audacity-408.mount
         10.796s mysql.service
          9.811s mpd.service
          9.269s networking.service
          6.924s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.682s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          5.257s bolt.service
```

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 10.971s
└─multi-user.target @1min 10.971s
  └─mysql.service @1min 173ms +10.796s
    └─network.target @1min 171ms
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @55.935s +2.813s
        └─dbus.service @55.884s
          └─basic.target @55.878s
            └─sockets.target @55.878s
              └─snapd.socket @55.876s +815us
                └─sysinit.target @55.735s
                  └─swap.target @55.735s
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-62ba7a95\x2d7374\x2d4862\x2daeb1\x2dc5
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-62ba7a95\x2d7374\x2d4862\x2daeb1\x2d
```

I checked out [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)   and did `sudo systemctl disable apport.service` and now `apport-autoreport.service` is not there. But `fstrim` is still taking a huge amount of time. I went through https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2410364 but wasn't able to get a satisfying answer.

This is the disk partition:
[image] 
  If you have any advice, I would be happy to hear! Thanks!

Comment: Run `systemd-analyze blame` in a terminal and it will list the startup times of all apps and units running when you boot the system.

Comment: Please also add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: To get rid of the `splash` screen, you can hit `ESC` (temporary) or open `/etc/default/grub`and remove `splash` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (DO A BACKUP BEFORE MODIFYING THE FILE). But I'm pretty sure this doesn't cause the ~3min boot time. Here is a handy one-liner to remove it: `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak && sudo sed -i s/splash// /etc/default/grub`

Comment: @KevInski, can you please help with getting rid of fstrim taking too much time.

Comment: There is nothing I can do about it, but take a closer look at [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2410364) thread. It may help you

Comment: do you have a swap partition on the ssd?

Comment: @Rinzwind added gparted screenshot.

Comment: you really should remove that and add a swap file.,

Answer (score 4):

To disable fstrim use:

```
rm /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-fstrim.timer
systemctl stop fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl disable fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl mask fstrim.service fstrim.timer
```

That will remove the 3m from your boot but does NOT fix the issue. You still need to hunt that down. For instance: do you have a swap partition? If so remove it and add a swap file to /etc/fstab and see if that was the issue. [swap partition vs swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file)

```
journalctl -u fstrim
```

will show a report on fstrim.

Mind that you should start fstrim manually if you do that and you can do that with

```
sudo fstrim -v /
```