# How to transfer space from SWAP partition to Ubuntu Filesystem partition?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, swap, disk, disk-usage

[image]

[image]

@heynnema
I have created a 127GB Swap partition instead of Filesystem partition while installing Ubuntu.
How can I transfer the Swap partition space to the filesystem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swap partition vs swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file)

Comment: Do you still need help with this? If so, I'll put together a detailed answer for you. Why did you set swap at 127G? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and a screenshot of `gparted`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited the question!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I haven't tried the solution yet. Will update you soon once I test it.
Btw, thanks for the answer )

Comment: @heynnema I have tried your solution(2nd one). Thanks for the solution.
1 more question. I have left 6GB of unallocated space for the SWAP partition.
How to make the SWAP partition?

Comment: No, you needed to follow ALL of my instructions EXACTLY. You can't start 1/2 way in. You don't need a 6G swap partition. If you followed my instructions, you'd now be using a /swapfile for swap, not a disk partition.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema How can I fix this?
How to make a swapfile instead of a disk partition!

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? **You need to follow ALL of my instructions in my answer EXACTLY. You can't start 1/2 way in.**

Comment: sudo swapoff -a
swapoff: cannot find the device for UUID=52a6f33f-f94e-4b4d-8b8f-1d31b491c889
@heynnema

Comment: That error occurs because you didn't follow my instructions the first time. Ignore the error and do the rest of my answer.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema It's working great now!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Turn off current swap

`sudo swapoff -a`

## Edit /etc/fstab

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

Comment out a line that looks similar to this (put a # at the beginning of the line):

```
UUID=52a6f33f-f94e-4b4d-8b8f-1d31b491c889  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Add this line at the end of the file:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Save the file.

## Create a new /swapfile

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

<strike>sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap</strike>

sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm other “swap” lines are commented out...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

## Edit partitions

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **swapoff** on partition /dev/nvme0n1p9
- **delete** partition /dev/nvme0n1p9
- **resize** the right side of partition /dev/nvme0n1p8 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: I tried the 2nd-way using Ubuntu Live USB in "Try Mode" and it solved my issue

Comment: No, you needed to follow ALL of my instructions EXACTLY. You can't start 1/2 way in. You don't need a 6G swap partition. If you followed my instructions, you'd now be using a /swapfile for swap, not a disk partition.

Answer (score 0):

**First option: change swap partition into a regular partition**

Run gparted from the menu. Choose the swap partition. Right-click the oversize swap partition and choose 'swapoff'. When this is done and you right-click again, you get a choice 'format to....'. Choose ext4.

Next, right-click on the new partition and click 'Information'. Save the value of the displayed UUID somewhere.

You need to manually create a mount point and and entry in /etc/fstab, such as

```
UUID=... /mynewmountpoint ext4 defaults 0 2
```

For ..., use the value you saved above.

Also remove swap from /etc/fstab.

**Second option: add the swap partition to the ubuntu system partition**

But if you want to add the space to the actual partition, then you need to boot from your ubuntu installation stick and run gparted from there (click on the applications grid at the lower left and search for gparted).

Right-click and delete the swap partition and then you can extend (resize/move) the ubuntu system partition.

Comment: Hm..., I didn't know "sudo gparted" still worked. Hasn't it been reworked years ago? Also, this doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: 'sudo gparted' works fine on my admittedly non-standard 20.04 system. I added an explanation how to add the space to the ubuntu partition.

Comment: Not really supposed to use gui apps with sudo. Things get saved into roots /home, not user's /home. It used to be gksudo, pkexec or sudo -H.  Not sure what is best, but you can just run gparted by selecting in gui menu. But cannot change mounted partitions and must also update fstab to remove swap entry. Use live installer to change partitions which has gparted as part of its default apps.

Comment: @oldfred: Incorporated these into my answer.