# How to change mounting point or resize root partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external HDD, it's been a huge pain.
I've followed a a guide on internet, where it was said that giving 40GB of space for the root partition would've been enough, now I'm seeing that with less than a quarter  of the program that I need it's already quite full.

[image: This is what GParted looks like]

I don't know if I should resize some partiton (and how) or maybe merging the two partition (`/home` and `/`).

Please don't tell me to redo the installation with different partition because it was a huge pain.

Comment: Your definition of "*quite full*" must differ from mine. Your image shows 27.08 GB of that 40GB still available on /, only 29% full.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/) and [How to transfer space from SWAP partition to Ubuntu Filesystem partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270863/how-to-transfer-space-from-swap-partition-to-ubuntu-filesystem-partition)

Comment: Since I had to install all kali library that was surely not enough

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you have provided, there is still more than 27GB of free space on sda2, which is the root drive, which is normally plenty, unless you're using very large applications, or MANY MANY applications.

If you still feel you need to repartition the root drive, you need to do the following:

1. Boot from your install media (DVD, or USB that you used to install ubuntu)
2. Choose the option to try Ubuntu (Not install). This should load to a desktop environment.
3. Use GParted in this temporary session to resize, and move partitions on your system as needed.
4. Reboot your system, when you're done.

For changing the size of the root, or home partitions on an existing installation, this is the only way, because you can't moved, or resize partitions that are mounted. Root, and Home are always mounted on normal boots.

Changing the mount point is more complicated, requiring much more work. (creating new partition, moving files from root to new partition, while keeping all permissions intact, editing fstab, and telling Grub where to find the new root.)

In my opinion, this is the easiest fix for your situation, based on the requirements of not doing a full reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I had to reinstall it anyway. when I moved the unallocated spaces on GParted a warn had shown telling me that I could've messed up the existing partition, and this happend. If I can ask you, we're you learned these thing?

Comment: I've got extensive computer experience, mostly in Windows. My linux experiences have been mostly through experience. This bit certainly is. I've installed Kubuntu (Ubuntu that defaults with KDE) many many times, and Ubuntu specifically a handful of times. I also have a LOT of experience with hard drive partitions, including adding, deleting, moving, and resizing. Those kind of warnings are rare in my experience, but usually worth heeding. Sorry this went badly for you.