# Why no Swap partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, vmware, swap

So I installed ubuntu onto a virtual machine and just realized that it no longer creates a swap partition. Why is this I thought those were important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swap partition vs swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file)

Comment: It defaults to `/swapfile` creation unless specified during a "Something Else" setup when installing the OS.

Comment: it's not shown in the list of partitions.

Comment: In a virtualized environment it is usually bad to swap in the guest. It could happen that the guest swaps in from it's file/disk onto a page that is swapped out by the host which needs to swap in ... - just bad. If anything then the host should have swap and if overall having a rather dense setup ballooning can be considered to further help. I can't find where (so no official answer) but I'm rather sure the installer considers that.

Comment: @Mintmag `/swapfile` is a file and not a partition so it will not show up in the list.  Look at `cat /etc/fstab` and you should see a line about swap in it.  Also, `swapon` from a terminal window will show you what swap is running on your system.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. So this is normal behavior than and a swap partition isn't necessary? What happens if you create one regardless?

Comment: Any thoughts on adding a swap partition when one is already created in the system