# How to extend my root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Lately my root partition is running out of space which is causing me problems, and I constantly have to free some space in order to avoid it. After 2-3 days my root partition gets full again. The only solution that i find is to increase the size of my root partition, but as a newbie on Linux systems I am afraid of data loss. My laptop  has dual boot of Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04. Is there any way that I can use the unallocated space that I created here in order to extend the root partition?

[image: Screenshot of partitions]

Comment: No, as i will have to move the unallocated space next to the root partition and i am not sure how to do that and where to move it

Comment: You don't "move" unallocated space.  You 1) delete your probably too small swap), move your root left to start at the start of the unallocated space, then extend it right (leaving enough room for (a bigger?) swap.

Comment: You did not make your root partition big enough.  25 GB has been the recommended **minimum** for Ubuntu Desktop since 2017.  Because you let your file system completely run out of space several times, you will probably have to reinstall the system. You might be better off not creating a separate home partition as you've just discovered why overpartitioning creates rigid and arbitrary limitations on how your system can make use of your space. Due to the cumbersome way you've arranged these partitions, moving/resizing is going to be extremely difficult.

Comment: FYI, you don't need a swap partition either. If you don't make a swap partition, your system will use a dynamically sized swap file. The partition size you chose for swap is also not really big enough to be useful.  This partition scheme is unviable and is overly partitioned.  I would recommend a single partition for the entirely of Ubuntu.  Delete (erase) partitions 5, 6, and 7 and reinstall Ubuntu to the much larger unallocated space at the end of the drive after your NTFS partition.  You will avoid all of the problems you created this time by overpartitioning / incorrect partitioning

Comment: @Nmath *"If you don't make a swap partition, your system will use a dynamically sized swap file"*... who told you that? Not true.

Comment: @hennema See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file - The size of a swapfile can be easily changed. The size of a swap partition cannot

Comment: @Nmath I'm totally aware of the difference between a swap partition and a /swapfile. My issue was with your statement that 1) made it sound like this was an automatic switchover, and 2) that the /swapfile is dynamic... it's not... it's a fixed size... to whatever size it was created with.

Comment: @heynnema if you are hung up on the word "dynamic" consider that I am specifically talking about swapfile creation during system installation which is in fact dynamically sized at that time based on system resources.  I am not talking about it automatically changing sizes after it is already set up.  A swapfile is overwhelmingly more flexible than a swap partition, which is my entire point

Comment: @Nmath re: *"swapfile creation during system installation which is in fact dynamically sized at that time based on system resources"*... I'm not sure that this is correct either. My observation is that this is not dynamic either... it ALWAYS creates a 2G /swapfile (which is ALWAYS too small), no matter how much RAM there is. I know what you were trying to say... my only disagreement what was implied... or what the thinking behind your understanding was. Peace :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll repartition your disk, as requested, but also convert you from a (too small) swap partition, to a /swapfile.

**Note**: Pay close attention to these instructions.

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

---

**DISABLE CURRENT SWAP PARTITION**

`sudo swapoff -a`

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

Comment out the swap line that looks *similar* to this...

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

---

**REPARTITION**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- set **swapoff** on /dev/nvme0n1p5
- **delete** the /dev/nvme0n1p5 old swap partition
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition all the way left
- **resize** /dev/nvme0n1p6 right side all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- quit `gparted` and reboot the computer

---

**CREATE /swapfile**

Now we'll create a fresh new /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm xxG RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Add the following /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

Then reboot and verify operation.

---

**RECOMMENDATION**

Reducing the size of the /dev/nvme0n1p7 partition, and creating a new NTFS partition, that can be used for sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly the answer I was looking for, as a new user on Linux. Worked perfectly.