# Default 17.04 swap file location

Tags: swap, 17.04

I could not find any information on this anywhere (and I don't want to set up a new 17.04 installation just for that), what is the default location of the swap file in 17.04?

Comment: The default location seems to be /swapfile. I am not sure what you mean by "...recreate ... after upgrade...". It would use the inherited swap partition happily.

Comment: @mikewhatever I meant how I can switch from using a swap partition to 17.04's default setup in that regard. But I see that I probably should not have combined two questions into one.

Comment: The answer is about finding, removing and creating swap in 17.04. You can follow any 16.04 method of re-creating the partition.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

2 commands:

```
~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -1
```

and

```
$ grep swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

So both point to:

```
$ cd / && ls -l swapfile
-rw------- 1 root root 2147483648 apr  2 18:56 swapfile
```

---

Disable and remove:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm /swapfile
```

---

Create a 2Gb swapfile, set permissions, format it as swap and enable it:

```
sudo fallocate -l 2g /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Also thank you for the commands on how to somewhat recreate 17.04's state. I read somewhere that the size dynamic but I guess this only refers to install-time, right?

Comment: yes. it does. Did not examine the effect on hibernation (but I would assume the file gets larger the more it needs).

Comment: I tried to test the commands in the last part you mentioned (which are also mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) but I'm getting `swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument` for the last command. I guess I might have to disable the swap partition first but I can't ATM because `swapoff: /dev/sdd8: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory`… guess, I have to free some memory.

Comment: hmmm how about using this from the live session?

Comment: Figured out that the problem had to do with `/` being btrfs, I missed that the FAQ mentions this fact.

Comment: Excellent answer, very helpfull form me and ubuntu 17.04. Thank you!

Comment: Can we add swapfile somewhere else like - `/datadrive/swapfile` ? Will that be a problem?

Comment: yes. Mind though that the file MUST be accessible during boot. If datadrive is a 2nd disk that is not mounted during boot it can be a problem. `/swapfile` just means at the root. The `/` can be any existing directory

Comment: Why need `cd` and not ls it directly instead? ie `$ cd / && ls -l swapfile` could be shorter as `$ ls -l /swapfile`