# Ubuntu 17.04 - doesn't have a swap partition?

Tags: system-installation, swap, 17.04

Why don't I have a swap partition in my installation?

```
$ lsblk
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 238.5G  0 part /
```

Did I install Ubuntu/ Kubuntu wrong?

I thought it should be like this:

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 222.6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1K  0 part
```

I just picked what was suggested during the installation. But it seems odd.

Comment: try `cat /proc/swaps`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. In fresh installations of 17.04 we have a swap file instead of a swap partition, as mentioned in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes) (if you upgrade rather than install afresh, you will still have a swap partition).

The swap file is located at

```
/swapfile
```

You can always check the status of swap with the command `swapon --show`.
Here's my output in 17.04:

```
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE  USED PRIO
/swapfile file 1.3G 62.2M   -1
```

You can also see if it's being used with the `free` command as usual

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        1.3G        152M         95M        423M        328M
Swap:          1.3G         62M        1.3G
```

See - working just fine.

According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap)

> There is no performance advantage to either a contiguous swap file or a partition, both are treated the same way.

It just provides a little more flexibility; it's easier to resize.

Minor note: Btrfs (alternative filesystem to ext4) does **not** support swap file usage, so you will need to create a swap partition yourself if you want to use Btrfs. But if you're brave enough to use Btrfs, you surely know what you're doing anyway ;)

Comment: @Zanna the /swapfile and a swap partition serve a similar function, except in the case of hibernation, correct?

Comment: If I just upgraded an older system that installed with a swap partition to 17.04, should I delete my old swap partition?

Comment: @cat - you should make that another question...

Comment: @HorusKol [Should I remove the swap partition on a system upgraded to 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/910339/455520)

Comment: `btrfs` has become production ready a while ago, it's only some features that are (still) experimental; it's not correct to treat the whole FS as experimental...

Comment: @heynnema if you hibernate on a system with a swap file, RAM contents are written to the swap file - it's the same. But I'm still trying to get it working on my system

Comment: Oh... does this new default mean that you'll have a hard time getting hibernation functionality if you don't think ahead of time to ditch defaults and add the swap partition? Or can you actually boot-resume from a swap _file_?

Comment: @Ruslan hibernation should work just as before, but it's always been a bit dicey. My device is a basketcase, and hibernation has presented me with different challenges in each version of Ubuntu. You can indeed (theoretically) resume from a swap file, as detailed in the Arch wiki.

Comment: @heemayl, `btrfs` is *not* production-ready.  I'm not aware of any data-loss bugs as long as you stick to basic functionality, but there are some non-obvious "gotchas" that could leave you with a permanently read-only filesystem, and others that could cause your computer to spend months or years performing an operation.

Comment: @Zanna my understanding is that the /swapfile will be max 2G by default, and doesn't have the same hibernation characteristics as a larger swap partition. To manually create a /swapfile, you need to use `fallocate` and then just create a /swapfile entry in /etc/fstab. You'd also want to remove the older swap definition in /etc/fstab, and delete the old swap partition.

Comment: @Zanna clarification. You might look at Rinzwind's command strings to create/use /swapfile at https://askubuntu.com/questions/904628/default-17-04-swap-file-location/904632#904632 (fallocate, chmod, mkswap, swapon) and an entry in fstab.